# Using Python class name to define class variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, classname

I have a class

```
class MyClass(object):
    ClassTag = '!' + 'MyClass'
```

Instead of explicitly assigning `'MyClass'` I would like to use some construct to get the class name. If I were inside a class function, I would do something like

```
@classfunction
def Foo(cls):
    tag = '!' + cls.__class__.__name__
```

but here I am in class scope but not inside any function scope. What would be the correct way to address this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Fix your typo of class definition first...

Comment: Thank you, was typing from head on auto-think :) not from code -- put in `def` instead of `class` -- now fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Instead of explicitly assigning 'MyClass' I would like to use some construct to get the class name.

You can use a class decorator combined with the `__name__` attribute of class objects to accomplish this:

```
def add_tag(cls):
    cls.ClassTag = cls.__name__
    return cls

@add_tag
class Foo(object):
    pass

print(Foo.ClassTag) # Foo
```

In addition to the above, here are some side notes:

- As can be seen from the above example, classes are defined using the
  `class` keyword, not the `def` keyword. The `def` keyword is for
  defining functions. I recommend walking through [the tutorial
  provided by Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html),
  to get  a grasp of Python basics.
- If you're not working on legacy code, or code that requires a Python 2 library, I highly recommend [upgrading to Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Along with the fact that the Python Foundation will stop supporting Python in 2020, Python 3 also fixes many quirks that Python 2 had, as well as provides new, useful features. If you're looking for more info on how to transition from Python 2 to 3, a good place to start would be [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Comment: @liliscent beautiful post at the same time with the exact same named content haha. :p

Comment: Thank you, was typing from head on auto-think :) not from code -- put in `def` instead of `class` -- now fixed. Very clever, thanks

Comment: Glad I could help @gt6989b!

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to write a decorator:

```
def add_tag(cls):
    cls.ClassTag = cls.__name__
    return cls

# test

@add_tag
class MyClass(object):
    pass

print(MyClass.ClassTag)
```